# Match Function in Specific Column Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, match, worksheet-function

I'm trying to write a program in VBA for Excel 2011 that can search a column (which column that is is determined by another variable) for the number 1 so that it knows where to start an iteration.

Say that the number of the column is given by `colnumvar`. The only way I can think of is the Match function, which led me to write the following:

```
Dim rowvar As Integer
rowvar = WorksheetFunction.Match(1,Range(Cells(1,colnumvar),Cells(1000,colnumvar)),0)
```

This gave me an error, however. After playing around with it some more, I realized that it must not accept the `Cells([row],[col])` way of doing it, but rather wants something like `Range("A1:A100")`. Unfortunately, I can't do it that way, since the program is figuring out what column to look in. Any help for figuring out how to get past this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the value of `colnumvar` when you run your code?

Comment: it's an integer whose value varies... it's always either 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, or 15. the point is that the code is supposed to be robust, so i can't just tell it what column to do, if that makes sense haha :P

Comment: Try putting .address after your range and after your cells so that you sure you are giving the match function addresses rather than values

Comment: I just tried that and it told me that there was a syntax error in the following: `BorradorVar = WorksheetFunction.Match(1, Sheets("Usuarios").Range(Cells(1, ColumnaNumVar, Cells(1000, ColumnaNumVar)).Address, 0)`. `ColumnaNumVar` is what I had written as `colnumvar` above.

Comment: Don't you think that 1 could be not found hence you get an error? `Range (cells (),cells ())` is correct syntax.

Comment: there's a 1 in each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean to do is better served with [`Range.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

```
Dim rngtrg As Range, rngsrc As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rngsrc = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,colnumvar),ws.Cells(1000,colnumvar))
Set rngtrg = rngsrc.Find(1,...)
rowvar = rngtrg.Row
```

Comment: thanks :D this worked well, but I had to change `Dim ws as Sheet` to `Dim ws As Worksheet`, and I got rid of the `...` in line 5. but apart from those trivial touchups, this code was amazing, thanks again!

Comment: @mataxu - I wrote the code without having Excel to test it. Fixed `Sheet` -> `Worksheet`. Argument `...` was not meant to be copied verbatim, but to be replaced by anything suitable for you, eventually nothing (see linked documentation).

Comment: oh that makes sense! thanks again :D it does exactly what i was going for

Answer (score 0):

this easy function retreive the positoin of that you find

```
Function rowvar(ByRef c As Integer) As Integer
    Dim keySrc As Integer
    keySrc = 22 'wath you want to find
    rowvar = WorksheetFunction.Match(keySrc, Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(1000, c)), 0)
End Function
```

use with rowvar(x)